# How to speed up Probit?

Tags: r, glm

I have a big model that I am running in R. To give you a taste of what I have,

```
Part2A = glm(lps1$POSINC ~ lps1$INCUND + as.factor(lps1$STATEICP) + as.factor(lps1$YEAR) + as.factor(lps1$HISPAN) + as.factor(lps1$MARST) + as.factor(lps1$WTE) + as.factor(lps1$BLK) + as.factor(lps1$MTY) + as.factor(lps1$HSG) + as.factor(lps1$SCL) + as.factor(lps1$HSDO) + as.factor(lps1$CBH) + as.factor(lps1$MCL) + lps1$NCHLT5 + lps1$MINCH, family=binomial(link="probit") )
```

(Sorry, I don't know how to put it on successive lines).

There are a total of 400000 data points per variable. This is the smallest I can make the data set. The only explanatory variable is INCUND, everything else is a control.

The probit takes a long time to converge. I've sat on it for 30 minutes. Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Regular line breaks work inside a code block. You just need to indent every line by (at least) 4 spaces.

Comment: 400k points isn't *that* big. You'll get a little bit of speed gain (and much more readable code) if you use the `data` argument instead of `lps1$` for every variable), that is `Part2A = glm(POSINC ~ INCUND + factor(STATEICP) + factor(YEAR) + ..., data = lps1)`. I'd also recommend running the `factor` bits on your data in advance rather than doing the work in the model.

Comment: And on that `factor` note, how many levels do those factors have? If some of your `factor` variables have very large number of levels that could slow things down as well...

Comment: Check out `install.packages('speedglm')`

Comment: Thanks. Some factors have 2 levels, but the State has 50+ (US and territories) and there are 6 years. I haven't thought about running the factor in advance. Can I just do that on the data frame?

Comment: I will install the speedglm package. Thanks.

Comment: Right, `lps1$STATEICP = factor(lps1$STATEICP)`. Now your column is a `factor` and you don't need to `factor` it again later. That doesn't sound too bad for number of levels. With binary variables there's no need to `factor` at all. But do make sure you don't have any with typos or text data or anything with 100s of levels.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it, that'll make my code quite a bit nicer and make life so much easier.